# is there a way you could put a delay between the two: this.bullets.push(this.ship.shoot());

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to add a delay between the two;
this.bullets.push(this.ship.shoot());

```
if (this.mscore >= 1000) {
  if (input.isPressed("spacebar")) {

    this.bullets.push(this.ship.shoot());
    this.bullets.push(this.ship.shoot());

  }
}
```

Comment: you could use `setTimeout()`

Comment: k I will try it

Comment: `input.isPressed("spacebar")` ?  Are sure this is JavaScript? If so, post the object or class that defines `.isPressed()` method.

Comment: So how would you have it layed out, and yes it is JavaScript the name ends with .js

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `setTimeout()`, in the next example, second code will be executed approximately after `1000ms`:

```
let delay = 1000;

if (this.mscore >= 1000)
{
    if (input.isPressed("spacebar"))
    {
        this.bullets.push(this.ship.shoot());
        let that = this;

        setTimeout(
            () => that.bullets.push(that.ship.shoot()),
            delay
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use setInterval or setTimeout

Below an example of setInterval, which will keep "shooting".

```js
const pressed = true
let interval = null

if (pressed) {
  shoot()
  interval = setInterval(() => shoot(), 1000)
} else {
  interval = clearInterval(interval)
}

function shoot() {
  console.log('shoot')
}
```